# SQL finding the top record per group

Tags: sql-server

Kind of stuck on a query. I have a table of quiz results which contains:

```
ID of the player,  
QuizID, 
Number of seconds it took to complete the quiz, 
Number of correct answers
```

How would I find the winner of every quiz. = the player with the max number of correct answers AND minimum number of seconds for every QuizID

I have tried many ways and I just can't get the correct results. Hope someone can help out.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to happen if there are two players that have the same number of correct answers and the same time?

Comment: And what if one player has maximum of correct answers and another player has the minimum number of seconds?

Comment: AT:Mark If there are 2 players with the same correct answers and time then it will be the one who entered first, so lowest playerID would do here.
AT:ypercube I want the player with the least amount of time of the players with the most correct answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CTE will calculate place for each player in the quiz. main query filters first positions only.

```
; with quiz as (
   select QuizId, PlayerID, row_number() over (partition by QuizId order by count_answers desc, seconds) rownum
      from QuizResults
)
select *
from QuizResults
   inner join Quiz
      on QuizResults.QuizID = Quiz.QuizID
      and QuizResults.PlayerID = Quiz.PlayerID
where rownum = 1
```

Comment: I switched the 'asc' and 'desc' around because it was giving me the players with 0 correct answers :) works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

Unverified:

```
select ID 
from your_table 
group by QuizId
having max(count_answers) and min(seconds)
```